# android studio 0.8.13 permissions issues on linux

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I've used 0.8.9 beta installed with unzip to /opt and have not had these permissions issues til now.

Installed the zip to /opt with

sudo unzip 0.8.13 zipfile

Now to run ./bin/studio.sh i have to use 'sudo'.  I dont think that was required with the 0.8.9 beta of AS.

Running the IDE with 'sudo' makes me a little nervous for the following reason...

I do my gradle builds at the CLI as my normal user ( not sudo ).

If i have invoked gradle commands from within the IDE then im left with residue of files belonging to ROOT that will cause subsequent CLI builds to fail on 'permissions errors' .

I will try the 'desktop' gui approach but im more comfortable at this point just to invoke AS with './studio.sh'

I tried unpacking the IDE zip to /home/myuser/android-studio and that caused a huge pile of permissions issues in the IDE for some reason ( maybe workspace residue related ).

Comment: delete it from /opt and install it to some directory your user owns. like ~/apps

Comment: tried to install AS in ~/  and got tons of permissions errors in the IDE ( maybe due to workspace residue ) .. Ill try ~/apps.